# How to get Elixir AST from local function

Tags: function, erlang, elixir, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to get the AST from a local function that is passed as an argument like `doSomething(fn a -> a * 10 end)`

So I tried

```
  def test do
    inspectAST(fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)
    inspectAST(quote do: fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)
    inspectFunctionInfo(fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)
    :ok
  end

  def inspectAST(this_is_AST) do
    IO.inspect(this_is_AST)
    IO.inspect("--------------------------------")
  end

  def inspectFunctionInfo(fun) do
    IO.inspect(Function.info(fun))
    IO.inspect("--------------------------------")
  end
```

Results :

```
iex(3)> Utils.test
#Function<0.30424669/2 in Utils.test/0>
"--------------------------------"
{:fn, [],
 [
   {:->, [],
    [
      [{:a, [], Utils}, {:b, [], Utils}],
      {:+, [context: Utils, import: Kernel],
       [
         {:+, [context: Utils, import: Kernel],
          [{:a, [], Utils}, {:b, [], Utils}]},
         42
       ]}
    ]}
 ]}
"--------------------------------"
[
  pid: #PID<0.485.0>,
  module: Utils,
  new_index: 1,
  new_uniq: <<58, 7, 203, 172, 99, 108, 54, 80, 24, 151, 75, 56, 73, 174, 138,
    177>>,
  index: 1,
  uniq: 30424669,
  name: :"-test/0-fun-1-",
  arity: 2,
  env: [],
  type: :local
]
"--------------------------------"
```

What I want is the result from `inspectAST(quote do: fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)` ( the AST ) but I would like to send the function like `inspectAST(fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)` without the `quote do:`

If anyone has some idea about this, your help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a "function" to be called on the AST, not values, it should be a macro, not a function.

The following should be a good base for what you want to achieve:

```elixir
  defmacro inspectAST(ast) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect(unquote(Macro.escape(ast)))
      :ok
    end
  end

  def test do
    inspectAST(fn a,b -> a + b + 42 end)
  end
```

- you need to use `defmacro` to treat your parameter as AST, not a regular value
- we want `IO.inspect` to happen at runtime, not compile time, so we need to return the AST for it using `quote`
- what we want to inspect is the content of the `ast` variable, so we are using `unquote`
- but `unquote` will unescape `ast` as well, so we need to escape it once more using [`Macro.escape/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Macro.html#escape/2)

Please note that the macro should be defined before calling it, so `defmacro` has to be before `test`, not after.

For more advanced explanations about macros, you should check this [serie of articles](https://www.theerlangelist.com/article/macros_1) which is very detailed.

Comment: @VictorSchröder Please disregard, I seem to misread the question.